# Download Modis LAI/FPAR product with MODIStools R package

Tags: r, remote-sensing, modis

I want to download the full MODIS archive for the LAI product using the  MODIStools R package.

I am running the command lines below but the output file only contains data from 2014 onwards. Any idea why I do not get the full time series (2000-2015)?

```
lat <- c(23.6947, 37.0894)
long <- c(60.8786,  79.3074)
period <- data.frame(lat=lat,long=long, start.date=2000,end.date=2014,id=1)
MODISSubsets(LoadDat = period, Products = "MOD15A2",
             Bands = c("Lai_1km", "Fpar_1km", "FparLai_QC"),
             Size = c(0,0))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could adapt the following code that uses [MODIS package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MODIS/index.html) to download monthly NDVI for two months in 2013. You need a different "product" and SDSstring.

```
library(MODIS)
runGdal(
    job        = 'NDVI',
    product    = 'MOD13A3', 
    SDSstring  = "1",         
    collection = '005', 
    extent     = 'Italy', 
    begin      = "2013.01.01", 
    end        = "2013.02.28",
    mosaic     = TRUE,
    outDirPath = '.'      # so that we don't have to look for the PROCESSED folder.
    )
```